# Marking a Non-Language GitHub Repo With a Language?

Tags: github

I have a GitHub repo that is just a Markdown file, although it's reference material specifically about CSS. I don't have any .css files for the repo but I'd like GitHub to be able to flag the repo as a CSS repo the same as it tracks other languages in repos. Any suggestions on how to best do this?

Comment: Would it be appropriate to put your CSS examples in seperate CSS files as well as inline and link them from the markdown? That might trigger GitHub to say it is CSS.

Comment: @BookOfGreg I had a similar idea, I'm just checking to see what the options are. Thanks.

Comment: You may find this question better asked on WebApps.SE ([github tag](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/github)).  The key point of WebApps.SE is it is about how to use web applications such as github.  Issues of markdown, sorting, and how github itself works are well within the scope on that site.  See also [Where does my git question go?](http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/q/6311/40980) from Meta.Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make it so that CSS makes up the majority of your repository.
One approach could be having your examples as full CSS files in their own right and linking in from the markdown.
Documentation on how GitHub decides language for a repo [is here](https://help.github.com/articles/my-repository-is-marked-as-the-wrong-language/).

Comment: Given it doesn't appear in the [samples](https://github.com/github/linguist/tree/master/samples) list, probably not.